# Dúvida análise regressão logistica no R

Tags: r, regressão

Analise R, possível análise logística, estou com dificuldades em analisar um dado onde várias espécies de sapos vocalizam, durante a coleta de dados a vocalização teve presença ou ausência entre intervalos de 5 em 5 minutos durante 12 horas (Os dados dos 5 minutos de coleta totalizara 144 amostras). Como proceder?

Onde faber é uma espécie de anfíbio, só consegui chegar até este ponto.

```
rm(list=ls())

dados=read.csv("teste.csv", header=T)

dados$Tempo <- factor(dados$Tempo)


names(dados)

#REGRESSÃO LOGISTICA

# Análise de distribuição de B. faber
dadosfaber<-glm(faber~Tempo, family="binomial")
summary(dadosfaber)

# Calculando o intervalo de confiança
confint(dadosfaber)

# Calculando o intervalo de confiança com o erro padrão
confint.default(dadosfaber)

#
exp(cbind(OR = coef(dadosfaber), confint(dadosfaber)))
```

Comment: Seja bem-vinda Érika, comece fazendo o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, para que alguém possa te ajudar, precisamos que você forneça um [**MCVE**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), leia [**Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824).

Comment: Bem vinda,  más otimizaria usando lm ao inves de GLM, o lm já calcula confiança e erro padrão.Se presença ou ausencia for em escola 0e 1(para presença ou ausência de qualquer vocalização), poderia aplicar a técnica de dummyes, más tudo indica que seu resultado séria, a influencia da presença de vozes em relação a faber (que devera ser quantidade por período talvez) não tenho certeza se é algo conclusivo para seu estudo, boa sorte!